# closed and continuous map

Tags: general-topology

**Let $f : X → Y$ be a continuous map from a maximal compact space onto a topological space $Y$. Then $Y$ is maximal compact if and only if the map f is closed**.

**Proof**. Suppose that $f : X → Y$ is closed. Since $f^{-1} \{y \}$ is compact whenever
$y \in Y$ , we see that $f^{-1} (K )$ is compact whenever $K$ is compact in $Y$ . Since $f^{-1} (K )$ is closed, we conclude that $K = f(f^{-1} (K ))$ is closed and hence $Y$ is a compact KC-space.

For the converse, suppose that the map $f : X → Y$ is not closed. Consequently there is a closed set F in X such that fF is not closed.  The compact set $f(F)$ witnesses
the fact that Y is not a KC-space.

> (a):**In the first paragraph:    is $f^{-1} \{y \}$  compact due to perfect map ?**
>
> (b):**In the sconde paragraph:   Why is set $f(F)$ compact? why?**

Comment: It would be awfully nice if you’d learn about [accepting answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer); there’s a very good discussion of the subject [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). With a reputation of $\ge15$ you can also upvote answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $X$ is $KC$ and therefore $T_1$. Let $y\in Y$; $f$ is surjective, so there is an $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. $X$ is $T_1$, so $\{x\}$ is closed in $X$, and therefore $f[\{x\}]=\{y\}$ is closed in $Y$. Finally, $f$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is closed in $X$ and therefore compact, since $X$ is compact.

$F$ is closed in $X$, and $X$ is compact, so $F$ is compact. Continuous maps preserve compactness, so $f[F]$ is compact.

Comment: Is $f^{-1}( K)$ compact by means of the same proof $f^{-1} (y)$? or  can we say " because of perfect map $f$ ( Theorem 3.7.1 from Engelking) $f^{-1}( K)$ is compact" ?

Comment: @fatemeh: You mean Theorem $3.7.2$. You can’t quite use it directly, because Engelking requires the domain of a perfect map to be Hausdorff, and $X$ here need not be Hausdorff. However, Engelking’s *proof* of that theorem works even if $X$ is not Hausdorff.